# Sumproduct with Substitute

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a range, containing numeric values & blank cells. Some of the numeric values will have * as suffix.

```
10* 5 7  9  25* 10
```

When I do a SUM(A1:A8), I get result of 5+7+9+10 = 31, the required output.
Now, I also require the total sum irrespective of * suffix. I'm trying to solve by using

```
SUMPRODUCT(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A8,"*",""))
```

It works out to

```
SUMPRODUCT({"10","5","7","","9","","25","10"})
```

And outputs 0 since all are text values. When I use

```
SUMPRODUCT(value(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A8,"*","")))
```

It works out to

```
SUMPRODUCT({10,5,7,#VALUE!,9,#VALUE!,25,10})
```

and finally outputs #Value!. Can someone help me to solve this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Not a programming question. Should be asked at SuperUser

Comment: @brettdj, Actually I've searched StackOverflow for any answers before posting.. I found so many excel formula related questions posted here, I thought its normal...

Comment: This issue has been addressed here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261875/are-excel-formulas-on-topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that the blanks are the problem because when you use =VALUE("") you get an error. Try concatenating a zero to the start of SUBSTITUTE so that blanks become zeroes

`=SUMPRODUCT(VALUE(0&SUBSTITUTE(A1:A8,"*","")))`

or you can use +0 in place of VALUE, i.e.

`=SUMPRODUCT((0&SUBSTITUTE(A1:A8,"*",""))+0)`

Comment: Nice one! So simple, can't believe it didn't occur to me. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=SUM(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A8,"*","")))
```

and enter it with Ctrl + Shift + Enter, instead of just Enter. This makes it an array formula, and it will treat the `A1:A8` range as an array for the `SUBSTITUTE()` function. Thus, `SUBSTITUTE()` now evaluates each individual value in A1:A8 separately. `VALUE()` converts the text to numbers, and sum() adds all of them up.

**Edit:** The formula `=SUMPRODUCT(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A8,"*","")))` seems to be working for me. (Normal formula, not an array formula).

Comment: As you see, I'm trying to avoid Array formula and prefer to use SumProduct instead...